# Custom URL Ivy dependency

Tags: ivy

I need to get the Scala.js library as a dependecy in a Ivy-using Eclipse project. Sbt manages to find the dependencies with no problems, but I can't seem to make it work with Ivy.

The jar is available here: http://dl.bintray.com/content/scala-js/scala-js-releases/org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-library_2.10/0.4.2/jars/ I've tried to construct a suitable Url resolver but with no success so far.

Supposedly the dependency in ivy.xml should work like this:

```
<dependency org="org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" name="scalajs-library_2.10" rev="0.4.2" />
```

What do I need in ivysettings.xml to make Ivy pull down the jar for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <url name="scala">
            <artifact pattern="http://dl.bintray.com/content/scala-js/scala-js-releases/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/jars/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.scala-lang.*" resolver="scala"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

This settings file is designed to retrieve from Maven central by default.

Comment: I had tried something similar, but that worked. Thanks a lot!